# Parsoid with MediaWiki VisualEditor returning 500

Tags: php, mediawiki, parsoid

I configured a Parsoid service for the Visual Editor for MediaWiki 1.24.1, configured as a private wiki. I can access both the api endpoint and the parsoid endpoint, but when I try to start editing using the VisualEditor I get this error:

```
Erro ao carregar dados do servidor:  parsoidserver-http-bad-status: 500: error: Page Fetch failure for "http://server.domain.in": 404 path: /working/file
Error: Page Fetch failure for "http://server.domain.in": 404
at ApiRequest._requestCB (/usr/lib/parsoid/src/lib/mediawiki.ApiRequest.js:172:11)
at Request.self.callback (/usr/lib/parsoid/node_modules/request/request.js:123:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/parsoid/node_modules/request/request.js:1047:14)
at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/parsoid/node_modules/request/request.js:998:12)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:929:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13). Gostaria de tentar novamente?
```

The first thing wrong is that the full domain is http://server.domain.inter.com, and it seems that for some reason it is not ok.

The configuration in /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js is

```
parsoidConfig.setInterwiki( 'interwiki', 'http://server.domain.inter.com/wiki/api.php' );
```

And the LocalSettings.php has

```
 require_once "$IP/extensions/VisualEditor/VisualEditor.php";
 // Enable by default for everybody
$wgDefaultUserOptions['visualeditor-enable'] = 1;
// Don't allow users to disable it
$wgHiddenPrefs[] = 'visualeditor-enable';
// OPTIONAL: Enable VisualEditor's experimental code features
#$wgDefaultUserOptions['visualeditor-enable-experimental'] = 1;

// URL to the Parsoid instance
// MUST NOT end in a slash due to Parsoid bug
$wgVisualEditorParsoidURL = 'http://localhost:8142';
// Proxy to use for curl requests.
// false: use direct connection to Parsoid daemon ($wgHTTPProxy is not 
// either)
$wgVisualEditorParsoidHTTPProxy = false;
// Interwiki prefix to pass to the Parsoid instance
// Parsoid will be called as $url/$prefix/$pagename
$wgVisualEditorParsoidPrefix = 'interwiki';
```

Comment: Did you try following https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor#Linking_with_Parsoid_in_private_wikis ?

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: This was a long time ago, and I don't remember how I solved it. Sorry.